# Updating jqplot Pie Chart via JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I am trying to update jqplot PieChart via JS since yesterday and I am not having any breakthrough with this. I have searched online and cant seem to get any solution work

The chart data is saved in session and this session is continuously being updated by the application.

This is what the JSON looks like

```
[ ['Take home pay', 44228.33], ['Tax', 8771.67], ['Super', 4162.5 ], ['Regular expenses', 0 ], ['Unallocated', 44228.33], ['Testing', 8000] ]
```

The chart loads fine when the user navigates to the page for the first time.

This is the DIV where the chart loads

```
<div id="savings_expense" class="jqplot-target"></div>
```

This is the `jqplot` JS when the page loads which works fine

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var storedData = <?php echo $_SESSION['chart_data'] ?>;

    var plot1;
    jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = false;
    plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('savings_expense', [storedData],
        {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer

            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 6
                },
                placement: 'outside',
                location: 's',
                marginTop: '15px'
            }
        }
    );
});
```

This is the button that user clicks to update the chart.

```
<li onclick="updateGraph()"><a href="#pay">YOUR TAKE-HOME PAY</a></li>
```

I have tried two ways to update the PieChart

**Solution 1**
In this solution I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replot' of undefined`.

```
    var storedData = <?php echo $_SESSION['chart_data'] ?>;
    var plot1;
    function renderGraph() {  
        plot1.replot({
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 6
                },
                placement: 'outside',
                location: 's',
                marginTop: '15px'
            }
        });
    }

    function updateGraph() {
        alert('updateGraph');
        var newVal = <?php echo $_SESSION['chart_data'] ?>;
        storedData.push(newVal);
        renderGraph();
    }
```

**Solution 2**
In this solution the pie chart goes blank but the legends stay

```
var storedData = <?php echo $_SESSION['SMP']['chart_data'] ?>;
var plot1;
function renderGraph() {
    if ( plot1) {
        plot1.destroy();
    }

    jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = false;
    plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('savings_expense',[storedData],
        {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer

            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 6
                },
                placement: 'outside',
                location: 's',
                marginTop: '15px'
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I will really appreciate any help here. Please do not share any links as I have gone through about every solution I could find on StackOverflow and on net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep on `document.ready` code as it is and then add function `updateGraph` outside `document.ready` (keep all variable at global level). Also modify `updateGraph`, here you need to call `.replot()` on `plot1` variable as you are only changing data and not other setting.

put id to `li`  like this : `<li id="updateGraph"><a href="#pay">YOUR TAKE-HOME PAY</a></li>`

See below code :

```
// declare variable outside document.ready
var plot1;
var storedData; 

$(document).ready(function () {

    storedData = <?php echo $_SESSION['chart_data'] ?>;


    jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = false;
    plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('savings_expense', [storedData],
        {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer

            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 6
                },
                placement: 'outside',
                location: 's',
                marginTop: '15px'
            }
        }
    );

    $('#updateGraph').click(function(){updateGraph();});
});

function updateGraph() {
     var newVal = <?php echo $_SESSION['chart_data'] ?>;
    plot1.destroy();
    plot1.series[0].data = newVal;
    plot1.replot(true);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback, i did try this solution as well. After moving the functions inside `document.ready` i get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateGraph is not defined `

Comment: you don't have to move functions inside document.ready, it should be outside.

Comment: So you are saying I only have to make variable global and it should work?

Comment: yes, make variable global and functions outside document.ready as shown in answer. You can copy paste answer.

Comment: I have updated your answer by removing the `$_SESSION[chart_data]` and replacing it with dummy data. I do not get any error, I can also see when in `generate` function data gets updated but this still does not update the graph and its legends

Comment: have you call plot1.destroy(); before calling replot? share jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: I have created this jsfiddle with some code changes, please look into it ... is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/KMd49/39/  change old  and new values, i think this should work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55982/discussion-between-baig-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, truly appreciate it. I wish I can give you million points for this